# What are cabal components and how do I use them?

Tags: haskell, cabal, cabal-install

`cabal build --help` and others mention `components` like in sentences like

```
Build one or more targets from within the project. The available targets are   
the packages in the project as well as individual components within those
packages, including libraries, executables, test-suites or benchmarks. Targets
can be specified by name or location. If no target is specified then the
default is to build the package in the current directory.
```

From the [cabal user guide](https://cabal.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setup-commands.html?highlight=component) mentions them too in `9. Setup.hs Commands`, and
gives two prefixes `exe:` and `lib:` to select those. Are there more of those prefixes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A component is anything behind a stanza with its own set of dependencies, etc. So it can be multiple sublibraries, multiple executables, test-suites, etc.

You're right that this is underdocumented! In the source code we can see the following (https://github.com/haskell/cabal/blob/00a2351789a460700a2567eb5ecc42cca0af913f/Cabal/src/Distribution/Simple/BuildTarget.hs#L569)

```
matchComponentKind :: String -> Match ComponentKind
matchComponentKind s
  | s `elem` ["lib", "library"]                 = return' LibKind
  | s `elem` ["flib", "foreign-lib", "foreign-library"] = return' FLibKind
  | s `elem` ["exe", "executable"]              = return' ExeKind
  | s `elem` ["tst", "test", "test-suite"]      = return' TestKind
  | s `elem` ["bench", "benchmark"]             = return' BenchKind
  | otherwise = matchErrorExpected "component kind" s
  where
    return' ck = increaseConfidence >> return ck
```

So that's the full list!

Comment: I updated the answer to give a full list pulled from source.

Comment: No better documentation than the implementation, i guess :-p